# How to show the same elements in Forge as in Revit?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

- In Revit the elements are showed
- But in Forge (Autodesk Viewer) does not.

e.g.

- View Range Floor Plan is 1.80m. I have tried it either with a View Template and without it.
- Of course the elements are bellow 1.80m (cube, Point of sell

Element Properties
[Element Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHEvb.png)

View Range Floor Plan
[View Range Floor Plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vjX9.png)

Floor Plan in Revit
[Floor Plan in Revit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9t5M.png)

Floor Plan in Forge
[Floor Plan in Forge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cM7D.png)

Additional Info:

- Revit version 2021.1.7
- In other View of other file the elements are showed in Forge as in Revit but not in the rest of views that have the same problem. I have not seen any difference in configuration. (Then I do not think the problem is a Revit version)
- Also, I use Postman to upload the file and transform, but I get the same results than viewer.forge.com.
- One could think it only happen to elements with and Elevation from level grater than zero, but it does not happen in other view that I do not have this problem.
- Yes, I have this problem in more than one file.

Comment: I'm assuming you're referring to the small blue boxes in the Revit floor plan, is that correct? Have you checked whether the "Point of Sale" element is included in the floor plan's "Visibility/Graphics Overrides" settings? Can you please share any special settings you might be using there?

Comment: Ideally, if you could share the Revit design with us (confidentially) via `aps (dot) help (at) autodesk (dot) com`, we'd be happy to investigate the issue on our side.

Comment: Yes, the blue boxes, point of sale, fryer. Yes I checked all in "Visibility/Graphics Overrides". I will send a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer from Autodesk:

> This issue is related to the limitation about scale in dwfx format,
> such issue has been resolved in pdf export.
>
> So the workaround for customer would be putting their plan view into
> sheet view with large sheet size.

Then after putting either the plan view or the ceiling view in a sheet view, it works.